# Не запускается программа с адреса 0x0800 1800

Tags: flash, stm32

Появилась необходимость освободить первые 3 страницы flash памяти. Основная программа должна выполняться начиная с третьей страницы 0x0800 1800 . Программа не стартует после сброса.

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD01e.png)]

В настройках проекта было сделано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из среды IAR все прошивается и запускается. Но, не запускается если просто подать питание на плату или вместо System reset поставить птичку Core reset. В чем моя ошибка?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE9AL.png)]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Возможно надо реализовать это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091858/moving-the-vector-table-on-an-stm32f405